# Neo4j syntax error: Invalid input '.': expected "FOR" or "IF"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import data in neo4j version 5.6.0 CE but I'm getting this weird error:

Invalid input '.': expected "FOR" or "IF".

I'm trying to run the following:

```
:begin
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX company.node.v2: Address FOR (n:Address) ON EACH [n.`city`,n.`department`,n.`identification_number`,n.`latitude`,n.`longitude`,n.`region`,n.`uid`,n.`zip_code`];
:commit
```

Can someone help me understand why I get this error and how I can solve it?
Thanks in advance

I tried looking at documentation and other posts on stackoverflow but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your index name ("company.node.v2: Address") is specified incorrectly. The name cannot normally have embedded colons, spaces, and periods (unless you surround it with backticks).

If you actually wanted to use the index name `Address`, do this instead:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX Address FOR (n:Address) ON EACH [n.`city`,n.`department`,n.`identification_number`,n.`latitude`,n.`longitude`,n.`region`,n.`uid`,n.`zip_code`];
```

or just this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX Address FOR (n:Address) ON EACH [n.city,n.department,n.identification_number,n.latitude,n.longitude,n.region,n.uid,n.zip_code];
```